# A consumer needs to know that all messages have been handled, before dealing with the data they contain

Tags: java, activemq-classic, producer-consumer

If I have a stateless message consumer, which is waiting for several asynchronous messages to come, how can I make sure that I have received all the messages, before I start working with the data that I get from them? In other words, I would either need something like an intermediary state storage, which is bound to a particular session, or something like `waitForAll()`.

What does ActiveMQ provide in that direction?

Comment: How can your consumer be stateless in such case ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use some kind of counter for each message you receive from the user? When the counter has reached the number of messages you are expecting, then do whatever you need to do.

Could you give us some more information as to what you are trying to do?